# Translation of "to play favorites"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, modismos

What is the best Spanish translation of the English idiom "to play favorites" (as in favoring individuals in a group instead of treating everyone equally)?

Answer (score 3):

For children we use "Consentido" meaning your favorite one.

In general, use "Preferido" as Laura stated the Mexican slang is "Enchufado"

Comment: I think your answer relates to "favorite", but I don't see clearly how does it relate to the original question idiom  "to play favorites".

Comment: It is traditionally say that your "Consentido(a)" is your favorite child because  you let them getaway with stuff. And "prferido" is a person hum you give all the easy jobs to when you have a choice.

Comment: I think these two words have potential and I've upvoted.  However, I'm going to rework the two ideas in a separate answer, for more precise accuracy.  (Hopefully.)

Answer (score 2):

I would say

> *favoritismo*, *favoritismos*.

Here's the definition given in the DRAE:

> [favoritismo](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?LEMA=favoritismo).
>
> (De favorito).
>
> 1. m. Preferencia dada al favor sobre el mérito o la equidad, especialmente cuando aquella es habitual o predominante.

Comment: Less formal "Estar enchufado" or "tener enchufe".

Comment: @Laura: that may be a regionalism, where have you heard it? Doesn't mean this in Argentina.

Comment: @Petruza Sorry, I'm from Spain.

Comment: Sorry for the edit: I got confused with the comment by @Laura

Answer (score 0):

My answer will focus on *verbs*.

If you don't mind sounding a bit like a canned translation of an article, you can use "jugar favoritos."

In conversation, common ways of dealing with this are:

**consentir** ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/consentir): to spoil)

> Mi mamá le consentía a mi hermano, pero era muy estricta conmigo. | *My mother spoiled my brother but was very strict with me.*

**tener preferencia** ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/preferencia): *tiene una clara preferencia por la hija mayor* | he has a clear preference for his eldest daughter / his eldest daughter is his clear favourite)

> Mi mamá tenia preferencia por mi hermano.

Answer (score -1):

*To play favorites* -> **Jugar a favoritos** -> **Más jugados**

*He is favorite of the teacher* ->   **Es el enchufado de la maestra**

Comment: I don't understand "más jugados."

Comment: @walen - I guess you understood "más jugados" because you had the confidence to do an edit -- can you help me understand what the author meant with that part?